# How to deal with On hold flag?

Tags: support

I asked [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68518/is-there-a-way-to-pass-to-execute-immediate-only-once-a-variable-but-use-it-seve) question in the DBA SO.

It was put on hold because it is too localized.

I don't understand why is considered too localized. I am asking a generic question on how 
to pass parameters with **Using**.

The poster that marked my question as too localized all said my question was "Laziness". But he didn't explain me why is laziness not wanting to repeat a parameter to avoid errors.

If this question doesn't belong to **DBA SO** and it should instead be in **SO** I will move it. I would just like to understand why, because it is not a specific question, I am asking this to apply it in several places.

Besides, I think many people with a background in other programing languages will struggle with this also, we are always told not to repeat, and here I have to repeat the same thing a bunch of times.

We are going to be changing some packages and I am creating a series of scripts to test that the changes don't break. As consequence I am sending lots of parameters with Using (To a CURSOR and other EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statements) and it seems prone to error to have to repeat them so much.

Should I delete the question and move it to SO? Or how should I change my question so the "put on hold" gets removed?

Comment: You should edit the question and try to explain better what you are after or why you need this. Questions can be reopened.

Comment: The question has been reopened.

Comment: @ypercube I open the question here, because I am not sure what to add to make it more generic. If you do a question too generic everyone will ask me to put a sample and what for I want that, that is why I went for the example right away.

Comment: @PaulWhite thanks, should I delete this question?

Comment: No need to delete it, thanks for bringing the issue up here on meta.